# Azure APIM deployment is getting failed. "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure"

Tags: azure-api-management

Deployment is getting failed for Azure APIM with the below error.

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
        "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'."
    }
}
```

---

Below is the ARM template for APIM:

```
{
       "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
       "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
       "name": "[variables('apim-name')]",
       "location": "[parameters('location')]",
       "sku": {
           "name": "[parameters('apim-sku')]",
           "capacity": "[parameters('apim-capacity')]"
       },
        "identity": {
            "type": "UserAssigned",
            "userAssignedIdentities": {
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('Identity-name'))]": {}
            }
        },
       "dependsOn": [
           "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', variables('vnet-name'))]",
           "[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('Identity-name'))]",
           "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',variables('vnet-name'),variables('apimsubnet'))]"
       ],
       "resources": [
           {
               "type": "gateways",
               "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
               "name": "my-gateway",
               "dependsOn": [
                   "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', variables('apim-name'))]"
               ],
               "properties": {
                   "locationData": {
                       "name": "My internal location"
                   },
                   "description": "Self hosted gateway bringing API Management to the edge"
               }
           },
           {
               "type": "loggers",
               "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",                    
               "name": "AppInsightsLogger",
               "dependsOn": [
                   "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', variables('apim-name'))]"
               ],
               "properties": {
                   "loggerType": "applicationInsights",
                   "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('app-insights-name'))]",
                   "credentials": {
                       "instrumentationKey": "[reference(variables('app-insights-name')).InstrumentationKey]"
                   }
               }
           },
           {
               "type": "diagnostics",
               "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
               "name": "applicationinsights",
               "dependsOn": [
                   "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', variables('apim-name'))]",
                   "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/loggers', variables('apim-name'), 'AppInsightsLogger')]"
               ],
               "properties": {
                   "alwaysLog": "allErrors",
                   "httpCorrelationProtocol": "Legacy",
                   "verbosity": "information",
                   "logClientIp": true,
                   "loggerId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/loggers/', variables('apim-name'), 'AppInsightsLogger')]",
                   "sampling": {
                       "samplingType": "fixed",
                       "percentage": 100
                   },
                   "frontend": {
                       "request": {
                           "body": {
                               "bytes": 0
                           }
                       },
                       "response": {
                           "body": {
                               "bytes": 0
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   "backend": {
                       "request": {
                           "body": {
                               "bytes": 0
                           }
                       },
                       "response": {
                           "body": {
                               "bytes": 0
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       ],
       "properties": {
           "publisherName": "[variables('apim-publisher-name')]",
           "publisherEmail": "[parameters('apim-publisher-email')]",
           "virtualNetworkType": "Internal",
           "virtualNetworkConfiguration": {
               "subnetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', variables('vnet-name'), variables('apimsubnet'))]"
           }
       }
   },
```

Comment: The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'
can be caused by many different things. Please post the whole error message including the "details" field; you can find the full error message by looking at your deployments in the Azure Portal and clicking the "(Error details)" link and then clicking the "Raw Error" tab.

Comment: You can refer to [Troubleshoot ARM template deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/quickstart-troubleshoot-arm-deployment?tabs=azure-cli#troubleshoot-the-deployment-error) and [Deployment Fails with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'](https://github.com/Azure/RDS-Templates/issues/373)

Comment: You can refer to a similar issue: [Creating API Management - The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/373420/creating-api-managemenet-the-resource-operation-co.html)